# Как задать тип константы в Си?

Tags: c

К примеру, в программе (для экономия места) я использую символьный массив для хранения и операций над значениями. При этом есть одно число: 9 - которое имеет важное значение, и которое, в целях практичности мне нужно записать как константу

```
#define SIZE 9
```

При этом, насколько я сумел понять из учебника, эта константа будет иметь тип `int`. В результате при операциях с этим значением будет все время использоваться приведение типа к `int`. Это меня не устраивает - я хочу знать, можно ли явно задать тип (символьный) такой константе?

Comment: это не константа, это просто define. Нужна константа - пишите `const char SIZE = '9';`, если Ваш компилятор это поддерживает. Но оно как бы все равно не совсем "символьное".

Comment: Статический массив из одного элемента? Только учтите, выравнивание никто не отменял, так что смотрите карту памяти после линковки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тип литерала в `#define` (и в любом другом месте) задается неявно и определяется тем значением, что вы укажете. `9` имеет тип `int`, `'9'` - тоже `int`, но соответствующий отличному от предыдущей ситуации значению (об этом далее), `"9"` - `char[2]` (строковый литерал, в котором один символ это `'9'`, а второй - терминирующий ноль `'\0'`), `9.0` будет иметь тип `double`, `9.f` - `float` и т.д.

В любом случае для `#define` вы задаете то значение, которое можно будет использовать в нужном контексте. Хотя здесь и возможны ситуации, когда компилятор молча проглотит, казалось бы, ошибочное значение. Например, при попытке задать массив:

```
#define N '9'
int A[N];
```

вы получите массив из 57 элементов (соответствует ASCII коду символа `'9'`), а не из 9 элементов.

В общем, чтобы понять более точно вашу проблему, хорошо бы увидеть конкретный пример, почему требуется явно указать какой-то специфический тип для дефайна.

Comment: Для дефайна тип НЕ задается, один и тот же дефайн может быть развернут потом во что угодно.

Comment: @bukkojot речь о типе *литерала* в дефайне, а не самого дефайна. Ну и приведите пример разворачивания *во что угодно*, пожалуйста.

Comment: Я думал, что define size '9' будет иметь тип char... Вообщем сам вопрос уже не имеет смысла: причина по которой я его задал, отпал - но за ответ спасибо.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch в сях символьный литерал типа '9' имеет тип int, а вот в c++ будет char. Есть такой тонкий момент.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Но вообще интересен контекст вашего вопроса. Поэтому хорошо бы добавить пример использования, даже есть проблема отпала. Вопрос может быть интересен другим участникам.

Comment: Все как и писал: есть массив символов а[4] = {0, 1, 2, 3} (именно так, а не '0'). Над ним производятся операции, в том числе: a[0] = a[0] - SIZE;. При этом, так как а[0] char, а SIZE int, то сначала произойдет приведение к типу int, потом вычисление, а потом урезание к типу char. Вот и все.

Answer (score 7):

Смотрите как работает define, самый первый этап компиляции это препроцессинг, везде где встречается ваша директива 'SIZE', она будет заменена на 9, а только потом будет компиляция, линковка.. Вы можете написать туда что угодно в рамках синтаксиса, это будет работать как если бы в блокноте произвели поиск и замену.

Comment: А чтобы посмотреть, что получилось после поиска и замены, можно запустить gcc -E

Comment: Я не понимаю зачем ты это написал - вопрос вообще-то о типе. С тем же успехом мог бы рассказать что такое "выражение" или "компилятор".

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
#define SIZE (static_cast<char>(9));
```

Мне подобное приведение требовалось при сборке пакета для отправки данных железу.

Answer (score 0):

Тип численной константы задается суффиксом

U или u - unsigned int (2 или 4 байта)

L или l - long (4 или 8 байт)

UL - unsigned long (4 или 8 байт)

LL - long long (8 байт)

ULL - unsigned long long (8 байт)

.  - double

F  - float

9.0 -- double

9.0f -- float

9LL -- long long int (64 бита константа)

и в выражении крайняя левая константа или переменная задают тип результата